# Get a specific value from array

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, access, workflow-variable, loop

I'm having this situation
[image: More array variables (in loop) with more values]

Inside a loop I'm having one more loop where I append specific values to a specific array. What if later I want to access the Trend value from the third array?

I know how to do that for the first array - first(variables('arrayIndustries'))?['Trend'], but what about the other ones?
I have tried variables('arrayIndustries')?[2]?['Trend'] to get the trend value from the second array but this gives me empty value.
I appreciate the help since I'm an intern and new to this

Answer (score 0):

Use following expression:

```
variables('arrayIndustries')?[2].Trend
```

My simple test for your reference:

[image]

Result:

[image]